The space $C_c$ of real-valued compactly supported, continuous functions is not a Banach space under any norm
This answer showed the space $c_{00}$ of compactly supported sequences, is not a Banach space under any norm.
I wonder if the same is true for the space $C_c$ of real-valued compactly supported, continuous functions:

$C_c$ is not a Banach space under any norm.

From this question the space $C_c$ is a complete space with some topology which is not metrizable.

If you assume the axiom of choice, this is false.
Indeed, notice that $\mathcal C_c(\mathbb R)\supset \mathcal C_0([0,1]),$ hence
$\text{dim}(\mathcal C_c(\mathbb R))\ge \mathfrak c$. On the other hand,
since $|\mathcal C_c(\mathbb R)|\le |\mathcal C(\mathbb R)|=\mathfrak c,$ it follows that $\text{dim}(\mathcal C_c(\mathbb R))=\mathfrak c$. Hence $\mathcal C_c(\mathbb R)$ is linearly isomorphic to any other $\mathbb R-$vector space having dimension $\mathfrak c$.
Now just pick your favorite infinite dimensional separable Banach space $X$ (which necessarily has dimension $\mathfrak c$) and transport the Banach norm to $\mathcal C_c(\mathbb R)$ using the isomorphism.
The reason why this fails for $\mathcal c_{00}$ is that $\text{dim}(\mathcal c_{00})=\aleph_0$ (since $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Hamel basis of the space); indeed, the same argument as in the answer linked in the OP proves that no Banach space can have dimension $\aleph_0$. A somewhat more complicated version of the same argument can be used to prove that given a $\mathbb R-$vector space, there exists a norm on it turning into a Banach space if and only if $\text{dim}(X)^{\aleph_0}=\text{dim}(X)$
